# Can't select the thumbnails view in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, toolbar

I lost the thumbnail view panel for *Print Layout* in Word 2007.
However, in the “*Show/Hide*” tab, it’s not grey, but the check box for thumbnails just can’t “hold” my selection.  The only thing can be shown is the “*document map*” view panel. When I click on *thumbnails view*, the whole side panel disappears.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you have hit a bug in Word 2007 (so also a chance that this will fix itself). Meanwhile you may be able to show thumbnails by calling the following code:

```
Sub OpenThumbnails()
ActiveWindow.Thumbnails = True
End Sub
```

with **Developer, Macros** and selecting OpenThumbnails, **Run**.

I am not clear whether this has affected a single document or all your documents. If the latter the code should be inserted in Normal.dotm but to begin with I suggest trying it out within just one document known to have the problem.